# Error: *** glibc detected *** w5: double free or corruption (fasttop):

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

This is the error i am getting:

```
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 00:28 2955225621  /home/w5/w5
...more
Aborted
```

My program compiles perfect, also part of my output is correct. 
I have 3 files, w5.cpp, employee.h, employee.cpp.
I need to create a copy constructor, an assignment operator, and a destructor.

w5.cpp (its a little big).
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1435.txt

employee.h
    class Employee {

```
   int empNum;
   char* empName;

   public:
     //Constructor 
      Employee();
      Employee(int num, const char* name);

     //Copy Constructor
      Employee(const  Employee& source);

     //Assignment operator
      Employee& operator=(const Employee& source);

     //Destructor
      ~Employee();

      void display() const;
      bool isGreaterThan(const Employee&) const;

};
```

employee.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Employee.h"
#include <string.h>

Employee::Employee() {
   empNum = 0;
   empName= nullptr;
}
Employee::Employee(int num, const char* name) {

   if(num < 0 || strcmp(name,"")==0) {
      Employee();
   } 
   else {
      empNum = num;
      empName = new char[strlen(name)+1];
      strcpy(empName, name);
   }
}

Employee::Employee(const Employee& source) {

   cout << "Copy Constructor!"<<endl;

   if(source.empName !=nullptr) {
      empNum = source.empNum;
      empName = new char[strlen(source.empName)+1];
      //strcpy(empName, source.empName);
      empName = source.empName;
   }
   else 
      empName =nullptr;
}

Employee& Employee::operator=(const Employee& source) {

   cout << "Operator Assignment!" <<endl;          

   // check for self-assignment
   if(this != &source) {
       cout << "Operator Assignment 2" <<endl;

      empNum = source.empNum;
      delete [] empName;
      if(source.empName !=nullptr) { 
         empName = source.empName;
         //strcpy(empName, source.empName);
      }
      else
         empName = nullptr;
   }
   return *this;
}

//Destructor
Employee::~Employee() {
   delete [] empName;                     
}

void Employee::display() const {

   cout << empNum << empName <<endl;
}

bool Employee::isGreaterThan(const Employee& source) const {

   return true;
   //still need to code here
}
```

To compile this I use `g++ -std=c++0x -o w5 w5.cpp Employee.cpp`
After looking online regarding this problem I think I have a "non valid pointer" but i'm not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is in your assignment operator:

```
// these two lines should be removed
empNum = source.empNum;
delete [] empName; // this deletes the source's employee name! (bad)

if (source.empName != nullptr) { 
     empName = source.empName;
}
```

You shouldn't just assign your object's `empName` pointer to the memory allocated by `source` since `source` will delete this memory when the destructor is called. You should allocate new memory for the string and then copy into it:

```
// first delete our string if we've previously allocated memory for it
if (empName != nullptr) {
    delete [] empName;
    empName = nullptr;
}

// now copy the source's empName
if (source.empName != nullptr) { 
     empName = new char[strlen(source.empName)+1];
     strcpy(empName, source.empName);
}
```

Comment: If i use strcpy() i  am getting Segmentation fault

Comment: Because you dont allocate memory for empName in operator=

Comment: I initially said "copy constructor" but it's actually the assignment operator that's problematic. If you first allocate the memory as I've indicated above, then it shouldn't segfault.

Comment: oh yes, now the Segmentation fault is gone. but for some reason i cannot output empName. display function.

Comment: does it have a value to display? what do you mean when you say you cannot output?

Comment: I enter "1" for empNum and "abc" for empName

Comment: Does the employee number display? Please update your question to show the input and output.

Comment: oh nvm, i forgot to remove comments from strcpy from assignment opp. i can see the output now

Comment: See my updated answer for another issue with your assignment operator (in case you didn't see it the first time).

Answer (score 1):

Change it back to strcpy:

```
empName = source.empName;
```

Otherwise you are double freeing this pointer

Also your copy constructor correctly allocates memory, while operator= does not.

Answer (score 0):

In the copy constructor we are supposed to create copy of all the pointers .

```
Employee::Employee(const Employee& source) {

   cout << "Copy Constructor!"<<endl;

   if(source.empName !=nullptr) {
      empNum = source.empNum;
      empName = new char[strlen(source.empName)+1];
      //strcpy(empName, source.empName);
      empName = source.empName;
   }
   else 
      empName =nullptr;
}
```

the line "empName = source.empName;" will result in empName of the object as well as the empName of the src object pointing to the same location . Also the memory is leaked too .

in assignment opertor too you have the same problem . dont assign pointers do a strcpy or memcpy after you have allocated memory . also check for the pointer value before freeing it .